# Get data from top level controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application has a main controller that wrap the entire application and every page has its own specific controller.

I use the main controller to store those variables that need to be constantly updated by real time pushes from the API.

Sometimes I also need to use those data from sub-controllers but actually I don't know how to do it correctly.

Let say the main controller has an array of `items` and those are constantly updated (obviously the update process is more complicated):

```
angular.module('core')
.controller('MainController', ['service', function(service) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.items = [];

  service.on('update', function(newItem) {
    vm.items.push(newItem);
  });

}]);
```

On another page I have another controller, child of the main one:

```
angular.module('list')
.controller('ListController', [function() {

  var vm = this;

  // If I need to access my main controller to look through items,
  // what should I do?

});
```

I tried to use `$scope.$parent.main.items` but it doesn't retrieve items correctly...

I wish to avoid storing `items` in a `$rootScope` or a `$scope` and I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it, but unfortunately I don't know it...

Comment: [Here the link Access Parent scope in child ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227691/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller-when-using-controller-as-and)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Suresh B, I thought about a service but I would end up storing my items in `vm.items` and also in the service... I was wondering what happen if the list of items is huge and I keep those stored in 2 different places?

Comment: try broadcasting method, broadcast from parent and receive in child.